# Form submit - add extra params to each field and read them on the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to add several parameters to every field on the form which is submited.
But I don't know how to read those params on the server? Is this possible?

Something like:

```
<input name="1009_test" merc_key="1234" coli_key="9499" />
```

When submitted I can read only name attribute on the server side, like:

```
form["1009_test"]
```

Is it possible to read merc_key and coli_key on the server?

Comment: html elements has its own designated attributes. I don't understand why you need to have it inside the `input elements`. try to explore javascript or jquery to meet your goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the name + input value pairs from the form are submitted.  If you want to include the additional key values, I would use hidden inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="merc_key" value="1234" />
<input type="hidden" name="coli_key" value="9499" />
```

Are those extra keys static?  Or do they change on the client side?

Comment: You are right about hidden fields, I've figured it out that this is the only option. Fields are statis on the client side, name attribute being combined from several parameters.